# why row is not updating in my form inputs in angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app in which i have a table in which i will have one form row initially on page component load. Then when user will type anything in 'description' field so another row will be added.

Here is the `component.html` code

```
<tr *ngFor="let fullRow of rawCannedService; let rowIndex = index;">
<td scope="row" (click)="onTypeClick()">
    <span *ngIf="isTypeLabel">Labor</span>
    <select *ngIf="!isTypeLabel" class="form-control" (blur)="onTypeBlur()" [(ngModel)]="serviceRow['type']">
        <option value="part">Part</option>
        <option value="labour">Labour</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td *ngFor="let service of fullRow.row;let i=index" (click)="onCoumnClick(i)">
    <span *ngIf="service.labelVisible">{{service.label}}</span>
    <input type="text" *ngIf="!service.labelVisible" (blur)="onColumnBlur(i,service.name)" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rawCannedService[rowIndex].row[i]['variableRef']">
    <!-- <app-table-cell *ngIf="!service.labelVisible" [serviceObj]="service" [colIndex]="i" [rowIndex]="rowIndex" [columnState]="onColumnBlur($event)"></app-table-cell> -->
</td>
```

So it looks like this

[image]

THe process is that when modal is load so initially text will be there in place of inputs and when user will click on any column so it becomes editable input. Issue is that i have to add next row when user will type anything in `description` field. So currently row is adding but variables are not updating. It binds same values for next row also.  I am binding `ngModel` variables dynamically. Here is the result of after adding another row

[image]

Here is my `component.ts` code.

```
 columns = [
  { field: 'type', header: 'Type', width: '15%' },
  { field: 'desc', header: 'Description', width: '40%' },
  { field: 'price', header: 'Price', width: '15%' },
  { field: 'qty', header: 'Qty', width: '10%' },
  { field: 'hrs', header: 'HRS', width: '10%' },
  { field: 'subtotal', header: 'SUBTOTAL', width: '10%' }
 ];
singleRow = [
  { name: 'desc', label: 'Please enter description', labelVisible: true, variableRef : ''},
  { name: 'price', label: '$0.00', labelVisible: true , variableRef : ''},
  { name: 'qty', label: '0', labelVisible: true, variableRef : '' },
  { name: 'hrs', label: '0', labelVisible: true, variableRef : '' },
  { name: 'total', label: '$0.00', labelVisible: true, variableRef : '' }
 ];
 rawCannedService = [];

  onCoumnClick(index: number) {
   this.rawCannedService[this.selectedRowIndex].row[index].labelVisible = false;
  }
 onColumnBlur(index: number, field: string) {
   console.log('field : ', field);
   console.log('row : ', index);
   console.log('updated state : ', this.rawCannedService);
   this.rawCannedService[this.selectedRowIndex].row[index][field] = this.serviceRow[field];
   if (field === 'desc' && this.rawCannedService[this.selectedRowIndex].row[index]['variableRef'].length > 2) {
   this.selectedRowIndex++;
   this.rawCannedService.push({row : this.singleRow});
  }
}
```

Am i binding `[(ngModel)]` wrongly?

Here is stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdt7xq) for reference

Comment: hi can you please create one stackblitz?

Comment: it's hard to replicate whole login on stackblitz. can you create a bsic stackblitz where there is a table in which there will be a default row with input columns. and then on click of any button another row(with column inputs) will be added in row.

Comment: @kushalshah here is stackblitz for your reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdt7xq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahsan, you need add a "copy" of singleRow, not singleRow, else you has an unique row

```
push({row : this.singleRow.map(x=>({...x}))})
```